# markercluster not changing after setvisible

Tags: google-maps-api-3, visibility, markerclusterer

Currently I have a set of markers and I cluster them like this:

```
var markerCluster = new MarkerClusterer(map, cm_mapMarkers);
```

But I also have a set of filters which i use to set markers visible false or true.
Unfortunatly when I set the marker setvisible(false) the cluster count is not changing.

So I looked for methods to do this:

I tried the following:

```
MarkerClusterer.redraw();
MarkerClusterer.repaint();
```

Both resulting in : has no method 'repaint' has no method 'redraw'

Here is a JSfiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/tDYcX/30/

Anybody knows what I am doing wrong?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I managed to do it using markerclustererplus and using `markerCluster.setIgnoreHidden(true); and markerCluster.repaint();`

Comment: Dude guy! Been looking for this solution for weeks. Thank you.

Comment: markerCluster.repaint() works perfectly fine for me, thanks !!!

Answer (score 3):

The MarkerClusterer isn't really designed for that sort of thing. The easiest way to do what you want is to `clearMarkers()` then `addMarkers(markers)` with a new array of markers that match your filter.

Comment: The MarkerClusterer doesn't care/pay attention to the markers visible state, it only uses the position. The Marker is only added to the map when there is only 1 Marker in a cluster.

Comment: Perfect answer, I had an issue with the solution. This works.

Comment: I'm trying to overcome the flash, when clear/add, so it doesn't flash each time we idle, change zoom etc , any ideas ?

Answer (score 3):

After a while of trying, I found a solution that works, maybe helpful for someone out there ...

Save your markerCluster and your map (mymap) in variables.

Then loop throuth all of your available markers and to like this:

```
if (show) {
        markerCluster.addMarker(markers[i]);

        if (markers[i].getMap == null)
            markers[i].marker.setMap(mymap);
        showing++;
    } else {

        markerCluster.removeMarker(markers[i]);

        if (markers[i].getMap != null)
            markers[i].marker.setMap(null);
    }
```